# SuperMicro X9DRW-3TF+ can't PXE boot from add-in card

Tags: pxe-boot

We've been able to PXE boot a X9DRW-3TF+ based SuperServer via the built-in 10Gb networking, but we want to boot from an add-in network card that's running at 1gb and on our management network. The 10GB we're using for SAN.

However, it doesn't seem to be working and we can't figure out any other settings to enable it. The network card is an Intel E1G42ET which definitely supports it. We've enabled that PCI port in BIOS for PXE boot.

Ideas?

Comment: Is there a boot order for the NICs? Apparently there is a config utility "Intel® Ethernet Connections Boot Utility"

Comment: What exactly isn't working here?  Are you getting to the PXE stack at all?  Are you seeing any messages from the boot agent?  IIRC there's usually a master 'load option rom' setting in the Supermicro BIOS settings, that would need to be enabled.